# Open source actionscript/flash audio editor

Tags: flash, actionscript, audio, editor

I am looking for an open source browser based audio editor which shows a waveform and let me clip audio. Does anyone know of one?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry this may be a bit disappointing for now, ...but make sure you stay in the loop for this quite awesome flash based editor that will be available in [Aviary](http://aviary.com/).

A video from digimix here : http://www.digimix.com/

Have a read about it here : http://aviary.com/blog/posts/aviary-acquires-digimix

Answer (score 0):

makeownringtone.com

It hasn't been working great for me today but it's usually pretty good. You need a decent connection and the audio file can't be too large, but it shows the waveform and has a surprising number of options and editing tools.

Good luck.